# Alternative Android Date Picker (for Dates of Birth, DOB)

Tags: user-interface

I was wondering if there is any way to call the date picker that the contacts app uses, as oppposed to the date picker that chrome uses.

We've found users struggling to identify how input their birth year, due to the year picker appearing too much like a label.

The implementation in the contacts app, with the three exposed wheels, we feel is a much more intuitive way for a user to input their date of birth.

Apologies I'm not a dev but any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Standard Date Picker]

[image: Preferred Date Picker]

Comment: Are you developing the app or not? Development questions are considered off-topic here. I'm also slightly annoyed by the new date picker too, however, and if you're looking for a way to replace it on the user end, I'd gladly keep an eye on this.

Comment: I didn't realize you could tap on the year to select the year as I had tried it several times with my fat finger and nothing has popped up I actually came here to ask if I was seriously expected to step back one month hundreds of times, but thanks to your screenshot I tried again and was able to get the year picker to pop up